# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I know how to derive $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt = \pi/2$ using polar coordinates, but what can I do if the upper limit is not infinity?

Comment: This is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) which is non-elementary.

Comment: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf

Comment: I haven't tried it, but integrating to a straight line boundary requires the use of $\sec$ and $\csc$ in polar integrals. And then you'd probably integrate from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, and similarly for each section. BTW, it should be $\sqrt\pi/2$ in the description...

Comment: @T. Bongers. This is not the Gauss error function, but a transformation of it.

Answer (score 1):

The integral you mentioned is continuous, and therefore Riemann integrable on $[0,x] $.

However, its antiderivative cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, which usually include polynomials, exponentials, logarithms, trigonometric functions, etc. Indeed, its antiderivative is a transformation of the Gauss error function:

$$\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{ erf } x$$